# Recursive linear search method by using ending index

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def searchletter(letterdata,eIndex,letter):
    found_list=[]
    if eIndex==-1:
        return found_list
    elif letterdata[eIndex]==letter:
            found_list.append(letterdata[eIndex])
            return searchletter(letterdata,eIndex-1,letter)
    else:
        return searchletter(letterdata,eIndex-1,letter)
        
letterdata=['a','b','a']

print(searchletter(letterdata,len(letterdata)-1,'a'))
```

---

```
Expected Output:
['a','a']
```

Hello, I actually know the reason why I get an empty list. It is because when I call the function inside the function, it makes found_list empty again, so is there any method for code not to read `found_list=[]` after it executes first time?

Answer (score 2):

```
def searchletter(letterdata,eIndex,letter,found_list):
    if eIndex==-1:
        return found_list
    elif letterdata[eIndex]==letter:
            found_list.append(letterdata[eIndex])
            return searchletter(letterdata,eIndex-1,letter,found_list)
    else:
        return searchletter(letterdata,eIndex-1,letter,found_list)
        
letterdata=['a','b','a']

print(searchletter(letterdata,len(letterdata)-1,'a',[]))
```

You are creating a list everytime your function gets called either you need to have a global list that keeps appending the elements or you can pass a list as an argument.

Comment: Thanks, but parameters are obliged to be just letterdata eIndex and letter. So, is there any way to solve it without adding new parameter?

Comment: Actually, we could create an empty list outside of the function and write 'global found_list' inside the function. It works.